# Which part of this HTML template controls the scrolling?

Tags: html, scroll

I'm trying to create my own website using [this HTML5 template](https://html5up.net/read-only). In this link when I scroll down or up the tabs change (e.g., from "about" to "Things I Can Do"). Also note that if you click on one of the tabs (e.g., "Things I Can Do") the main website stays the same -- "https://html5up.net/read-only".

I'm extremely new to HTML and trying to figure out which part of the code (I'm not attaching it here because it's long and can be downloaded from the link) controls the scrolling, as I'm having 2 issues after modifying it for my needs:

1. When I click on one of the tabs the website change from `my_website` to `my_website/#one` or `my_website/#two`, etc.

I can see the part of the code that references that:

```
<li><a href="#one" class="active">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#two">Things I Can Do</a></li>
<li><a href="#three">A Few
```

but I'm not sure how to modify this to still scroll to the correct section (e.g., `about`) when I click on the `about` tab, without changing the website to `my_website/#one`

2. When I go to `my_website` and scroll only the last 2 tabs change when I reach their sections. Moreover, if I click on one of the tabs `about`, which as mentioned above changes the website to `my_website/#one`, the tabs don't change anymore even if I go to the next section on the page.

Apologies for not sharing my code, it's long and I didn't want to clutter this. I am happy to answer any questions! Again, I never touched HTML5 before so this is all new to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that on Clicking one tag then it goes to that section of page then use a attribute in style tag called `scroll-behavior: smooth` and then when you click on any tab it goes to that part of page.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Apologies. I don't quite understand what you just said. I tried to look for `attribute` in the code or `scroll` but didn't find anything. Are you saying I need to remove the code I referenced above (e.g., `href="#one"`) and replace it with something else? Because the original script already has scrolling. I must have modified something that I shouldn't have. Trying to figure out what is it

Comment: If you want that on clicking on any tab or on any wordit go to that particular section then you have to add 'scroll-behavior : smooth'  and that word or tab should be in the ' <a href = "#clients">'and you have to put that whole section in a div tag and give it the Id like Id = clients